# Cucumber SpringBoot +JPA test, repository returns null

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, cucumber

Getting results from JPA repository null in cucumber test. I know that results are in database. Probably not connecting. I am new to SpringBoot and not sure what is wrong.

Here is code and configurations below.
CucumberConfig.java

```
package com.xxx.xxx.cucumber;
import io.cucumber.spring.CucumberContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.TestConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;


//@TestConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {
    "com.xxx.xxx.configuration"
})
@CucumberContextConfiguration
@SpringBootTest
public class CucumberConfig {
}
```

CucumberRunner.java

```
import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import io.cucumber.spring.CucumberContextConfiguration;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;


@ContextConfiguration(classes = { CucumberConfig.class })

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
  features = "src/test/resources/features",
  glue={"com.xxx.xxx.cucumber"},
  plugin = {
    "html:target/site/cucumber/cucumber-report.html",
    "junit:target/site/cucumber/cucumber-report.xml",
  })
@ActiveProfiles("cucumber")
public class CucumberRunner {
}
```

ShipmentBackEndValidationTestsIntegrationTest.java (partial)

```
@Component
public class ShipmentBackEndValidationIntegrationTest implements CucumberStateVariables { private final RestTemplate restTemplate;
  private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ShipmentBackEndValidationIntegrationTest.class);
  final CucumberUtil cucumberUtil;
  AppConfig appConfig;
  CustomerShipmentRepository customerShipmentRepository;

  @Autowired
  public ShipmentBackEndValidationIntegrationTest(
    AppConfig appConfig,
    CucumberUtil cucumberUtil,
    OceanRestTemplateHelper oceanRestTemplateHelper,
    CustomerShipmentRepository customerShipmentRepository
    )
    throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException, KeyManagementException {
    LOGGER.warn("SU: {}", appConfig.getSecurity().getSystemUser());
    LOGGER.warn("SUP: {}",appConfig.getSecurity().getSystemUserPassword());
    this.appConfig = appConfig;
    this.cucumberUtil = cucumberUtil;
    this.restTemplate = oceanRestTemplateHelper.buildRestTemplate(oceanRestTemplateHelper.lrdUserAuth());
    this.customerShipmentRepository = customerShipmentRepository;
  }
```

ShipmentBackEndValidationStepDefs.java

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class ShipmentBackEndValidationStepDefs  extends ShipmentBackEndValidationIntegrationTest {

  private CustomerShipment requestShipment;
  private CustomerShipment ResponseShipment;
  private boolean expectException;
  private final List<RuntimeException> exceptions = new ArrayList<>();
  private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomerShipmentApiStepDefs.class);
  private String errorMessage;

 /* @Autowired
  CustomerShipmentRepository customerShipmentRepository;*/

   public ShipmentBackEndValidationStepDefs(
    AppConfig appConfig,
    CucumberUtil cucumberUtil,
    OceanRestTemplateHelper oceanRestTemplateHelper,
    CustomerShipmentRepository customerShipmentRepository
    )
     throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException, KeyManagementException {
     super(appConfig, cucumberUtil, oceanRestTemplateHelper, customerShipmentRepository);
     this.customerShipmentRepository = customerShipmentRepository;
   }

  @Given("shipment for {string} branch")
  public void shipmentWithValidAndIncompleteDataInCarrierDetailsIsCreatedForStringBranch(String branchCode) throws IOException {
    this.clearExceptionList();
    /* shipment is created */
    TestDataSerializer.changeTimezoneContextToBranch(branchCode);
    requestShipment = TestDataSerializer.generateCustomerShipmentFromJson("shipments/CustomerShipment.json");
      }


  @When("the user clicks the save button")
  public void the_user_clicks_the_save_button() {
    try{  this.ResponseShipment = saveCustomerShipment(requestShipment);
      LOGGER.info(String.format("Successfully saved shipment number: ", this.ResponseShipment.getShipmentNumber()));
      System.out.println("Shipment saved successfully: "+ ResponseShipment.getShipmentNumber());
    } catch (HttpClientErrorException err) {
      this.errorMessage = err.getMessage();
          }
  }

  @Then("the data is saved to the database")
  public void dataIsSavedToDatabase1(){
    String shipmentNumber = ResponseShipment.getShipmentNumber();
   
    Optional<CustomerShipment> resultShipment = customerShipmentRepository.findCustomerShipmentByShipmentNumber(shipmentNumber);
    System.out.println("Print -- "+resultShipment);
     assertTrue(resultShipment.isPresent());
  }
```

Repository

```
package com.xxx.xxx.shipment.repositories;

import com.expd.ocean.base_repository.BaseRepository;
import com.expd.ocean.shipment.entities.CustomerShipment;
import com.expd.ocean.shipment.entities.CustomerShipmentStatus;
import jakarta.transaction.Transactional;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.EntityGraph;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Modifying;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.UUID;

@Repository
public interface CustomerShipmentRepository extends JpaRepository<CustomerShipment, UUID>, BaseRepository {

  @EntityGraph(value = "CustomerShipment.fullCustomerShipment", type = EntityGraph.EntityGraphType.LOAD)
  Optional<CustomerShipment> findCustomerShipmentByShipmentNumber(String shipmentNumber);

  }
```